# How multiple recursion works?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I need help with a question I saw in my last exam.

> **Write the output of the execution of the following method by the call pX(7).**

```
  public static void pX(int x) { 
       if (x > 1) { 
        pX(x/2);   
        pX(x/2);  
       }  
       System.out.println(x); 
    }
```

I don't understand recursion when a method calls itself twice. I tried to solve problems with `multiple recursion`, but I just can't "invert" my mind in a way to multiple recursive thinking.

- Can someone explain how `multiple recursion` works?
- Is there any specific mechanism for understanding it?
- Will writing a recursion tree or stack call on a blank list will help to understand it?
- Is there any reading (like books or articles) about `multiple recursion` that's worth reading?

Comment: Please post the code and not an image of it

Comment: Generally, if you just go through it line by line, writing down what the current value of each variable is, you should be able to understand what is happening.

Comment: Can you explain what **exactly** is unclear to you?

Comment: I do not understand recursion when a method calls itself **twice** just i stand  when a method calls itself **once**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is when a method or function calls itself.

[Multiple Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Single_recursion_and_multiple_recursion) is when a method or function contains multiple self-references. This is when it gets a bit tricky. Lets take a look at your example.

You call `px(7)`, and since the parameter is over the value of `1` as your condition checks for, it will enter that code block and encounter the first recursive call, dividing your parameter by half, `px(7/2)`, which evaluates to `px(3)` (rounded down for integers).

Now that you've entered your first recursive call, **lets put your original call on hold for a sec** and focus on this new call of `px(3)`. Your condition determines that x is still greater than 1, so we encounter our *first* recursion within *this call*. So we call ourselves again, dividing the parameter by half, `px(3/2)` which evaluates to `px(1)` (again, rounded down).

Now our condition will no longer pass, so there will be no recursive calls within this iteration, We will go directly to `System.out.println(x);` and print out the value `1`

Back to where `px(3/2)` got called, the next line in that condition is to do it again. So we call `px(3/2)` again.

Still, our condition will not pass, so we will not call any more recursive calls and go directly to `System.out.println(x);`

And again, back to where that second `px(3/2)` got called. We've completed our condition block and can finally call `System.out.println(3);`

Here are your first three lines in the output, `1,1,3`

It can be kind of tricky, but you need to focus, retain and follow the call stack to really get this down.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanShalabi You're welcome very much. Please do not let the down votes discourage you. The stack overflow community can be a bit vicious to new comers who break the rules.